# Preg_match extract text between <a> and </a>

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have in code something like that:

```
<a href="http://www.allegro.pl/show_item.php?item=3069353216" target="_blank">Buty trekkingowe Chiruca Tasmania 12 GTX roz. 44</a>
```

now I want to extract from it: **Buty trekkingowe Chiruca Tasmania 12 GTX roz. 44**

Im geting data from imap (using PHP).
Varible item from that code is different for each data extracted so it hasto respect all numeric values there

Can you help me put together preg_match for it?

Comment: It would probably be better to use an HTML parser for this

Answer (score 0):

An example with DOMDocument:

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.allegro.pl/show_item.php?item=3069353216" target="_blank">Buty trekkingowe Chiruca Tasmania 12 GTX roz. 44</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$number = '3069353216';

$aNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($aNodes as $aNode) {
    if (preg_match('~=' . $number . '$~', $aNode->getAttribute('href')))
        echo $aNode->nodeValue;
}
```

If you want to checks several numbers and since `$number` is a part of a regex pattern, you can write:

```
$number = '(?:3069353216|30804254251)';
```

or you can generate it from an array:

```
$numbers = array('3069353216', '30804254251', ...);
$number = '(?:' . implode('|', $numbers) . ')';
```

if you don't need a specific number: `$number = '[0-9]+';`

if you don't need a number, you can remove the `if (preg_match...`